# macos on Synology VM manager

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, osx-lion, synology

I'm tring to create a macos virtual machine in synology nas with virtual machine manager.

Is there a way to build and to run in such a way an macos on synology nas ?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed IATKOS ML2 on VMM but it’s not the last version of macOS ... It’s a beginning

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It doesn't seem to be an answer to the question. Could you elaborate on it?